# How to set content of UIColletionView cell vertically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, nsarray

I am setting my json data inside UITableView which is inside UICollectionViewCell

**but I am getting data as**

```
-----------   -----------  ----------
|  Data 1 |   | Data 2  |  | Data 3 |
|         |   |         |  |        |
-----------   -----------  ----------
-----------   -----------  ----------
|  Data 4 |   | Data 5  |  | Data 6 |
|         |   |         |  |        |
-----------   -----------  ----------
```

**But I want my data to be displayed like this(means vertical)-**

```
-----------   -----------  ----------
|  Data 1 |   | Data 3  |  | Data 5 |
|         |   |         |  |        |
-----------   -----------  ----------
-----------   -----------  ----------
|  Data 2 |   | Data 4  |  | Data 6 |
|         |   |         |  |        |
-----------   -----------  ----------
```

I am passing my data array at each Indexpath.row from `CollectionView cellForRowAtIndexPath` to `TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` 
And at `TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am printing data which I am fetching as above to each Indexpath.row.

Comment: Is the collection has 4 cells only?

Comment: No it CollectionView has 28 cells (as 4 row & 7 columns) like a TIMETABLE. @BharatModi

Comment: Could you show some picture, what you have to do? As you are saying that your collectionView cell has tableView, it is bit confusing to know what exactly you want to do?

Comment: set `scrollDirection` Horizontal

Comment: by applying a custom layout?

Comment: No I can't use that because I have dynamic collectionView Header. I will change direction my header properties will also change. @AbhishekPM

Comment: I haven't used custom layout.. its flow layout. @holex

Comment: what I am saying is you __can__ create a custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property of the `UICollectionView` called `ScrollDirection`. I think it should change the scroll direction (obviously) and therefore the way the cells are layed out. You can find it in storyboard too in the Attributes Inspector when you have you collectionview selected.

Though doing that will only force the collectionview to layout the cells like you wanted, but you'll still have work to do to force 4 rows / 7 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You just set the scroll direction of collection view -

Programmatically -

```
Your_Collection.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

by storyboard or xib File -

[image]